# Javascript execute code, click button, wait until new page loads and click second button, etc

Tags: javascript

The question is simple, the answer is not (for me).

There is a page on which I run Javascript code in console (browser).
I want to execute the code (fill form) and click "Add button", wait until the next page loads and click next button, execute next part of code, click button, and so on.

I can't find a way to do this in pure Javascript - I'm not a developer. My code:

```
        function ReadData(rzad, kolumna) {
            var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("path to file");
            var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet");

            x = excel_sheet.Cells(14, 5).value;
            xx = excel_sheet.Cells(15, 5).value;
            xxx = excel_sheet.Cells(5, 17).value;
            xxxx = excel_sheet.Cells(5, 18).value;
            xxxxx = excel_sheet.Cells(5, 19).value;
            xxxxxx = excel_sheet.Cells(5, 20).value;
            xxxxxxx = excel_sheet.Cells(5, 21).value;
            xxxxxxxx = excel_sheet.Cells(5, 22).value;


        }

        ReadData();
        document.getElementById(x).click();
        document.getElementById('xx').innerText= xxx;

        **document.getElementById('firstaddButtonId').click();**
        **setTimeout(document.getElementById('SecondaddButtonId').click(), 5000);** 
**=>>it should be clicked after page loads after first button click.**
```

I tried setTimeout, window.onload and read several articles, but couldn't find answer - or understand maybe.

Comment: DOMContentLoaded event listener to the loaded page should do the trick

Comment: No offence my friend but `I'm not a developer.` , well find one!

Comment: Fill form, click button, |new page loads|, click button, |new page loads|, etc.